# Audio is extremely sensitive

Tags: sound, audio

I haven't been able to find anything about this type of issue. Anything below about 24% is completely inaudible. 40% and up is unbearably loud.

I have the output device set as my headphones, Corsair Vengeance 1500 Analog Stereo.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I fixed it, I fiddled with PulseAudio Volume Control's settings, accidentally set my headphones as input, and when I set it back to Analog Stereo Output it worked. Nice!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Can you mark this as answered? Thanks!